# Convergence in probability using normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I need help in solving this question:

> Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $...$ be $i.i.d.$ with distribution $N(2, 5)$. Prove that for some $n$, we have
>   $P(Y_1 + Y_2 +···+ Y_n > n) > 0.999$

I know from this, I need to find the new value of $\bar{Y}$ first, which is $$N\left(2, \frac{5}{n}\right)$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I don´t think that this is true. Have you calculated the case if $n=1$?

Comment: The answer should be $n \gt 5000$

Answer (score 1):

By Strong Law of Large Numbers $\frac {Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n} n \to 2$ almost surely . This implies $P(Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n >n) \to 1$. Note that the exact distribution of $Y_i$ is not required for this and even the variance is not required. CLT is an overkill for this question.

Comment: How do you know the probability converges to 1?

Comment: $P( Y_1+...+Y_n \leq n) \leq P( |\frac {Y_1+...+Y_n} n -2| \geq 1) \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You know $\bar{Y} \sim N(2, 5/n)$. Thus $Z:=\sqrt{\frac{n}{5}}(\bar{Y} - 2) \sim N(0,1)$. Further,
$$P(Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n > n) = P(\bar{Y} > 1) = P(Z > -\sqrt{n/5}).$$
As $n \to \infty$, this quantity tends to $1$.

As noted in another answer, there are more direct methods (under even more relaxed assumptions) to show that there *exists* an $n$ for which the inequality holds. The virtue of this method (which uses knowledge of the distribution of each $Y_i$) is that one can compute for *which specific values of $n$* the inequality holds.